# Setting Maximum Data Points for Range Selector and Interval

Tags: highcharts

I've got a chart that has a large number of data points.  I'm setting the extremes right now so it only shows a smaller number - about 100 or so at a time.  The issue I have is I don't want to disable the range selector or the manual input for dates, but currently the user can expand the range selector to include the entire data set.  Is there any way to limit this so they can only grab, at most, X number of points?

I don't want to use data grouping either, I have different data for different data groups, so it's important the grouping does not change.  Thanks in advance for any pointers on this one!

Comment: So as I assume you would like to display all points, am I right? If yes you can use setExtremes() http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setExtremes() for all range.

Comment: No, I'm only displaying a portion of the data currently.  I want to give them the ability to slide back and forth or to look at different time periods, but not increase the overall time period, thus adding more data.  Does that make sense?  I can try to put a jsfiddle together if that would help.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't disable range selector for such purpose, but you can overwrite extremes after user change them, see: http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.events.afterSetExtremes
So for example, if user takes range for 4 days and you want max for 2 days - grab one of min or max, and add/remove two days in extremes (call chart.xAxis.setExtremes() with new extremes). Of course, it will call another afterSetExtremes, so it would be infinite loop, however now extremes will be proper (two days), so it wouldn't call another setExtremes().

Comment: @PawełFus - Thanks for the information.  That kinda sucks but it is what it is, I may have to find some other way to do what I'm trying to do.  Do you want to add that comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't disable range selector for such purpose, but you can overwrite extremes after user change them, see:

api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.events.afterSetExtremes So for example, if user takes range for 4 days and you want max for 2 days - grab one of min or max, and add/remove two days in extremes (call chart.xAxis.setExtremes() with new extremes). Of course, it will call another afterSetExtremes, so it would be infinite loop, however now extremes will be proper (two days), so it wouldn't call another setExtremes().

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example of using afterSetExtremes (like Dexter describes) to create a maximum range from the range selector :

http://jsfiddle.net/B7vCR/3/

```
xAxis: {
            minRange:6 * 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000,
            events: {
                afterSetExtremes: function(e) {
                    var maxDistance = 10 * 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000; //8 months time
                    var xaxis = this;
                    if ((e.max - e.min) > maxDistance) {
                        var min = e.max - maxDistance;
                        var max = e.max;
                        window.setTimeout(function() {
                            xaxis.setExtremes(min, max);
                        }, 1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

From this post

http://forum.highcharts.com/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=21741